# I am trying to insert new user to my sqlAlchemy by using Python and Flask but keep getting an error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

here is my database model setup

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100),  unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='users_roles')
    backref = db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic')
# Here func that hashing password set it by user

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)


class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True)
```

Here is how I am trying to insert new user,

```
new_user = User(username="user1", email="user1@gmail.com",
                password_hash="hashed_password", roles="Admin")
db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.commit()
```

But I keep getting this error

```
", line 1385, in <listcomp>
    ((c is not None) and instance_state(c) or None, c)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

Can someone help me please??

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you initialize the role attribute of the user:

`new_user = User(username="user1", email="user1@gmail.com", password_hash="hashed_password", roles="Admin")`

because role refers to an object ry to change 'roles="Admin"' to the role object

Also c usually means a column and so it tries to get and attribute of a column (role object) and it gets the role as a str

Comment: You mean like this?

Comment: ```  roles={"name":"Admin"}```, it didn't work

Comment: you passed a dict not an ORM object.
can you get a role by name? for example something like:
role = Role.get_by_name('Admin')
if yes i'd try to put it inside the user